# Minimum Bounding Geometry Convex Hull

Tags: arcmap, convex-hull

I have 1000+ irregular shaped polygons where I would like to determine the orientation (azimuth) of their long axis. The polygons overlap in a few cases, if that matters. I am using the Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management) tool with the "Convex Hull" geometry type. When I run the tool, the resulting attribute table does not list anything except the length, area, and original feature ID -- not the MBG_Apod information and orientation  as described [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000).

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Turn them on here. The red line.

[image]